# How can I call a DLL from a scripting language?

Tags: python, perl, dll

I have a third-party product, a terminal emulator, which provides a DLL that can be linked to a C program to basically automate the driving of this product (send keystrokes, detect what's on the screen and so forth).

I want to drive it from a scripting language (I'm comfortable with Python and slightly less so with Perl) so that we don't have to compile and send out executables to our customers whenever there's a problem found.

We also want the customers to be able to write their own scripts using ours as baselines and they won't entertain the idea of writing and compiling C code.

What's a good way of getting Python/Perl to interface to a Windows DLL. My first thought was to write a server program and have a Python script communicate with it via TCP but there's got to be an easier solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way to call C libraries from Python is to use [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html):

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> windll.user32.MessageBoxA(None, "Hello world", "ctypes", 0);
```

Answer (score 12):

In Perl, [Win32::API](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32::API) is an easy way to some interfacing to DLLs. There is also [Inline::C](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Inline::C), if you have access to a compiler and the windows headers.

Perl [XSUB](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlxs)s can also create an interface between Perl and C.

Comment: Add in XS and we have ourselves a winner.

Answer (score 5):

In Perl, [P5NCI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/P5NCI) will also do that, at least in some cases.  But it seems to me that anything you use that directly manages interfacing with the dll is going to be user-unfriendly, and if you are going to have a user (scriptor?) friendly wrapper, it might as well be an XS module.

I guess I don't see a meaningful distinction between "compile and send out executables" and "compile and send out scripts".

Answer (score 4):

For Python, you could compile an extension which links to the DLL, so that in Python you could just import it like a normal module. You could do this by hand, by using a library like Boost.Python, or by using a tool such as SWIG (which also supports Perl and other scripting languages) to generate a wrapper automatically.

Answer (score 3):

The Python **Py_InitModule** API function allows you to create a module from c/c++ functions which can then be call from Python.

It takes about a dozen or so lines of c/c++ code to achieve but it is pretty easy code to write:

https://python.readthedocs.org/en/v2.7.2/extending/extending.html#the-module-s-method-table-and-initialization-function

The [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com) editor that I wrote, uses this appoach to allow [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com) macros to be written in Python and it works very well.

Comment: if you wrote an "hello world" example in your answer, instead of a link to a page that isn't practical, you would not be the latest of this answer list :-)

Comment: The link that I provided already contains a simple 'hello world' example.

From the link provided: "An example may be found in the file Demo/embed/demo.c in the Python source distribution."