# make python react immediately to one character of user input, like "read -n1" in bash

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, command-line-interface

If it was possible to get output from this shell script into a variable I think that would be the ideal solution.

```
import os
os.system('read -s -n 1 -p "Press any key to continue..."')
```

I have a shell script that reacts to one keypress immediately (because "read" with the option "-n1" is selected)  like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -s -n1 -p "" keypress
if test "$keypress" = "a"
then
    open ~/something.txt
fi
if test "$keypress" = "b"
then
    open ~/something_else.txt
fi
exit
```

How could I modify this to python 2 code to similarly react immediately to user input rather than waiting for the user to press return? (I use osx and would prefer a solution that only relies on the standard library, but anything that could work on both osx and linux would be fine.)

```
something=raw_input()
print "write a or b"
user_input_a='a'
user_input_b='b'
if something == user_input_a:
 print 'it was a'
if something == user_input_b:
 print 'it was b'
```

Comment: Are you on Windows? Try `msvcrt.getch`.

Comment: Nope. I updated my question. :)

Comment: trying  sys.stdin.read(1), it seems like I still have to press return, I'd like something that works the same was as the bash code above

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718561/python-3-how-to-input-data-without-pressing-return-in-osx/8718648#8718648

Comment: It is possible to get output from a shell script into a variable, but that's really not a good way to fetch a single character. Please see the answer linked in my previous comment for an OSX solution.

Comment: I saw it. That code as well as the code in the other answers mostly did not work when I attempted to copy paste it (with some modifications) and the code is a bit too complicated for me to fix it. I guess I'll stick with bash for now, but I've noted that the ncurses library may be a good option in the future.