# Performing code depending on input without pressing 'Enter'

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [raw_input in python without pressing enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523174/raw-input-in-python-without-pressing-enter)

Some of the code:

```
print "Do you want to (e)ncode?"
option = raw_input("> ")
if option == "e":
    print "Encoding..." # and some other code, which isn't important here
else:
    pass
```

What I want to do is that if you enter "e", it immediately performs the code in the block, without pressing 'Enter'.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Not possible with `raw_input`, but I can't say about using other means ...

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks! Sry for the duplicate.