# Python input without new line

Tags: python, python-3.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [raw_input in python without pressing enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523174/raw-input-in-python-without-pressing-enter)

How to capture python input without user pressing ENTER.

For example how to make cycle that user presses number and program prints it without pressing ENTER

Comment: Refer the duplicate question. There is an answer using `msvcrt`.

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary I mean Python 3.2.x

Comment: @JohnSmith http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.getch.

Comment: you can try my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68501240/16258342)