# How to enter a input without pressing enter

Tags: python, python-3.x

For instance I would like it so,

```
x = int(input("Please enter your guess :")
If x = 1:
   Print ("correct")
```

Although each time i need to press enter, **how could I make it so it would read on key press**.

I did find getch() although i could not get it to work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523174/raw-input-in-python-without-pressing-enter

Comment: I did look through that although i was hoping some one could provide me a example of how to use getch() for my example.

Comment: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892/ - getch()-like unbuffered character reading from stdin on both Windows and Unix (Python recipe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows you can use `msvcrt`. On other systems its a bit more difficult, take a look at this recipe: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892/

You can use it that way:

```
getch = _Getch()

print 'Please enter your guess: '
x = getch()

if (int(x) == 1):
    print 'correct'
else:
    print 'wrong'
```