# How to accept input without the need to press enter Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, user-input

i'm wondering how to accept input without the need to press enter. i searched online, and i get something regarding raw_input, but i think that became obsolete after the arrival of python 3.0.
sometimes, i run a while loop on a whole program since i want to ask the user:
continue? (y/n):

for instance consider the code:

```
import random

d = input('Toss coin? (y/n): ')

while d != 'n' and d!= 'N':
    c = random.randint(1,2)
    if c == 1:
        print('HEADS!')
    else:
        print('TAILS!')

    d = input('Toss coin? (y/n): ')
```

but i just want to add more flare to my program by just not having the user press enter everytime. just press y or n and the program loops or breaks accordingly.

ok so this is the new code:

```
import random
import msvcrt

d = input('Toss coin? (y/n): ')

while d != 'n' and d!= 'N':
    c = random.randint(1,2)
    if c == 1:
        print('HEADS!')
    else:
        print('TAILS!')

    print('Toss coin? (y/n): ')
    d = msvcrt.getwch()
```

but msvcrt still doesn't work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145535/how-to-enter-a-input-without-pressing-enter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using windows, `msvcrt` is the answer:

```
import msvcrt

print ("Please enter a value.")
char = msvcrt.getch()
print char
```

If you are not using windows, take a look at the following snippet at this [source](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892/):

```
getch = _Getch()
print ("Please enter something: ")
x = getch()
print x
```

Comment: do i have to import something for your code to work?

Comment: it's not working... says invalid syntax

Comment: ok i understand that perhaps _getch() only works on unix based systems

Comment: however, why do i have to use microsoft's library to do something in python? isn't there any way using only python? I remember being able to do somehting like this in java

Comment: nope, it works on both Windows and Unix!- more information [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892/)

Comment: yea, i know, in java i could offer you more solutions- but in python my knowledge is limited...

Comment: thanks buddy, works perfectly. i'll mark your answer right in 5 min

Comment: Just note that this obviously won't work in IDLE or any other environment that uses pythonw.exe or embeds python in a process that lacks a console.

Comment: ok thanks. i just spotted a problem also... when i use msvcrt in my code, the loop doesn't run but just prints what i entered as input

Comment: @amin: `getch` returns `bytes`. Use `getwch`.

Comment: hmm same thing happens

Comment: i posted new code under the old one. help please!

Comment: how does the loop not run? is there an error message?

Comment: suppose i enter 'y', the program terminates displaying the characater y.

Comment: and you are using the follwing code? :
d = msvcrt.getch()

Comment: tried with both msvcrt.getch() and msvcrt.getwch() as recommended by @eryksun

Comment: try to print the value you have captured in d in the line after the msvcrt.getch(); what does it say?

Comment: program still terminates and nothing prints. i am using eclipse by the way

Comment: hm...now you've got me clearly stumped... this could eventually solve your problem: [Using msvcrt.getch() in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076853/using-msvcrt-getch-in-eclipse-pydev)

Comment: seems to be a known issue: [Bug 375172 - msvcrt.getch() isn't parsed from Eclipse console](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=375172)

Comment: ah ok. so what i'm doing is correct, but however it does not work on eclipse right? thanks!

Comment: @amin, as I said it needs a console window. You could use ctypes to call `kernel32.AllocConsole`, and then open the special file `"CONOUT$"` to print to it, but you'd have to type into the console window for `getwch` to get the keyboard input messages.

Comment: hmm this seems quite complicated.. i'm just new to python.. i'll read up some more on what you mentioned. thanks