# Python sys.stdin.read() accept input condition print prompt twice

Tags: python, user-input, stdin, sys

I wrote a function that accepts a character (without hitting `enter`), and checks for validation, and returns the key pressed. But the problem is, the prompt I am printing is printing it two times if the value is not matched. Here is my code.

```
def accept_input():
    while True:
        print "Type Y to continue, ctrl-c to exit"
        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        if ch != "Y":
            pass
        else:
            return ch
```

and when called `accept_input()`, it is printing the prompt twice when there is a non matching character, and printing once if the input is blank.

```
python accept_input.py 
Type Y to continue, ctrl-c to exit
a
Type Y to continue, ctrl-c to exit
Type Y to continue, ctrl-c to exit
b
Type Y to continue, ctrl-c to exit
Type Y to continue, ctrl-c to exit
c
Type Y to continue, ctrl-c to exit
Type Y to continue, ctrl-c to exit

Type Y to continue, ctrl-c to exit

Type Y to continue, ctrl-c to exit
Y
accepted
```

Why is it printing twice when entering any non matching key, and why is it printing only once when a blank key is entered?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because after `a` you pressed `\n` too...so 2 characters.You can clear the buffer instead.

```
def accept_input():
    import sys
    while True:
        print "Type Y to continue, ctrl-c to exit"
        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        sys.stdin.flush()   #<===========
        if ch != "Y":
            pass
        else:
            return ch
```

Comment: Thankyou @vks, but the repeated printing of the prompt is still there. You enter any character, and the line `"Type Y to continue, ctrl-c to exit"` is printed twice.

Comment: @nohup r u sure you copied my code? coz for me if i type `a` only once the line `type Y` is getting printed.

Comment: Yep. Exact copy. I just corrected the indentation from the initial one.  Meanwhile, I have one more question. The purpose of this function, that is to accept input without an enter, was not working from the initial time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As you said, if I enter multiple characters, like `abc`, it iterates it and prints 4 times (including `\n`). I'm using `Python 2.7.9`

Comment: @nohup at my end it is not printing for `\n`.If you enter `abc` only `2` times the `line` is printed.the function is working as expected exlcuding `\n` from input....

Comment: @nohup may be this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523174/raw-input-in-python-without-pressing-enter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92236/discussion-between-nohup-and-vks).