# How to hide input in console in Python?

Tags: python

I have a menu as shown in the picture below.

[image: menu]

I'm waiting for an input from the user to choose one of the three. But when user enters something, for example `2`, it gets displayed in the console and it waits for the user to press enter. But I want it such that when the user hits a number, the menu disappears instantly. How do I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python read a single character from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user)

Comment: Perhaps [getpass](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/getpass.html#getpass.getpass) can help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [raw\_input in python without pressing enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523174/raw-input-in-python-without-pressing-enter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `keyboard` package. Install it by running `pip install keyboard` in your terminal and import it into your code with `import keyboard`. To detect the user input:

```
if keyboard.is_pressed('1'): 
    # do searach stuff
elif keyboard.is_pressed('2'):
    # show most used words
elif keyboard.is_pressed('3'):
    # Goodbye, exit
else:
    # (a) clear the screen (e.g. os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear'))   
    # (b) reprint the menu
    # (c) print "Bad input, try again"
```

You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python) helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the screen, something like this should work:

```
import os
os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
```