# how to get user input without pressing enter in python?

Tags: python, input, key

I am a c++ User and im am newly learning python,
i used to use `getch()` statements in c++ to get user input without having to press enter although it had some limitation ... I am looking for a similar function in python (anything other than `raw_input()` & `input()` which require enter key stroke). would prefer the code to have cross platform support

for eg in c++ :

```
void getkey()
{
_getch();
cout<<"You Hit A Key";
}
```

Comment: You can use `keyboard` package. https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/

Comment: @maciek97x, how do i use it ? a demo code would be helpful

Comment: Does this answer your question? [raw\_input in python without pressing enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523174/raw-input-in-python-without-pressing-enter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example using `keyboard`:

```py
import keyboard

while True:
    event = keyboard.read_event()
    if event.event_type == keyboard.KEY_DOWN:
        key = event.name
        print(f'Pressed: {key}')
        if key == 'q':
            break
```

Comment: This library requires root access in ubuntu at least

Answer (score 0):

You could do this if you are on a *windows* OS.

```
import msvcrt
print("Press y or n to continue: \n")
getLetter = msvcrt.getch()
if getLetter.upper() == 'S': 
   print("cool it works...")
else:
   print("no it doesn't work...")
```

Comment: this would work for windows but does it work with other OS ?

Comment: for which OS specifically?

Comment: I Code In Vc (Windows) But the function should be cross platform supportable (Linux,MacOS) @FishingCode

Comment: some of these have code that works across different OS systems, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523174/raw-input-in-python-without-pressing-enter) ...

Answer (score 0):

Was writing a simple drum machine on a Raspberry Pi using Python and Sonic Pi: press a key, play a sound. Here's the core of the input routine.

pip install getch

```
import getch

while True:
     key = getch.getch()
     if key == 'x':
          break
```