# Python code must accept multiple inputs and stop accepting inputs after the word end. How can I make sure to get the count of vowels after all input?

Tags: python

```
vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'

count = 0

text = input()

while text != "end":
    for i in text: 
         if i in vowels: 
            count += 1
            
    count  
    text = input()
    
#print(count)
```

I am not sure how to structure the code but please see below:

EXAMPLE INPUT:

```
input 1:I LOVE YOU
input 2:TEST
input 3:YOU
END
```

EXAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
5
1
2
```

The output should be the number of vowels in each input as per above example.

Comment: vowels='aeiouAEIOU'

count=0

text = input()

while text != "end":
    
    for i in text: 
        
         if i in vowels: 
                
            count += 1
            
    count  
    
    text = input()
    
#print(count)

Comment: Although there is no question here, I am guessing that your problem is that you need to move the `count = 0` line inside the `while` loop...

Comment: Your question seems to stem from a fundamental misunderstanding of the basic constructs of the language. I'm not sure how you expect the the current implementation to print something for each input without having a print statement within the loop itself. A beginner's tutorial in Python will probably answer your question better than anyone here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to create infinite loop (`while True`) and break out of it when we encounter word "end"

```py
vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'

while True:
    text = input()  # it will get a new value every time the loop executes
    count = 0  # note it'll be assigned 0 every iteration
    if text == "end":
       break  # end the loop, since we found the word "end"
    # if we get here, it means the word is not "end"
    for letter in text:
        if letter in vowels:  # letter is a vowel, increase count by 1
            count += 1
    print(count)
```

To first read all the text and only then count/print the result you could first collect all the strings in a `list`.

```py
vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'
user_text_list = []  # we create empty list

while True:
    text = input()  # get input from user
    if text == "end":
       break  # end the loop, since we found the word "end"
    # if we get here, it means the word is not "end"
    user_text_list.append(text)  # "save" the word in a list

# once we get here, it means we encountered the word "end" and we can count the vowels
for word in user_text_list:  # for each element of the user_text_list (user inputted word)
    count = 0  # initialize count to 0 every iteration
    for letter in word:
        if letter in vowels:  # letter is a vowel, increase count by 1
            count += 1
    print(word, count)  # print word and vowel count
```

There isn't really an easy way to do it. Python waits for user to press `[ENTER]` when using `input`. If that's what you want, please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523174/raw-input-in-python-without-pressing-enter).

```py
wordlist = []
while True:
    text = input()
    text = text.split(" ") # converts "I LOVE YOU" to ["I", "LOVE", "YOU"]
    for word in text:
       if word == "end":
           break
       wordlist.append(word)  # if word is not "end", add word to list

for word in wordlist:  # for each element of the user_text_list (user inputted word)
    count = 0  # initialize count to 0 every iteration
    for letter in word:
        if letter in vowels:  # letter is a vowel, increase count by 1
            count += 1
    print(word, count)  # print word and vowel count
```

Comment: Code-only answers to code-only questions really puts down the bar of quality this site strives to. First of all try to only answer well-asked questions, and further if you decide to answer them, at least add some explanations to your answer to make them a bit more valuable...

Comment: Why do you print the `text` along with the `count`?

Comment: I agree, I believe comments included in the answer should provide necessary context.

Comment: @Tomerikoo I agree that *more* explanation is needed, but saying there's no explanation at all is inaccurate as there's explanation in the form of comments.

Comment: @RoyCohen There wasn't really any reason, other than my preference. I edited the answer to provide a bit more explanation and removed the unneeded print

Comment: Thank you this. how would i input all my text and only get each lines number of vowels after the end

Comment: @Kholofelo Start by editing your question to explain that. Provide a few example inputs and how you expect your program to work with them

Comment: @Kholofelo I edited the answer to show how to do this. Please try to edit your question to explain what you want more clearly and ask more directed questions in the future

Comment: AS IN HOW WOULD I GET THE ELOW: EXAMPLE INPUT:
I LOVE YOU
TEST
YOU
END

EXAMPLE OUTPUT:
5
1
2

Comment: @Kholofelo Please see if the final edit solves your doubts

Comment: it solves it. than you very much