# Take Input While the User is Typing? Python

Tags: python, input

I was wondering if there is a way to take input while the user is typing in python. I was planning to use this to make a sort of danger notes for Windows, but there is no way currently that I have found that allows the program to get the user input while the user is typing. To be more specific, I was hoping there is something I could do, to, get each key typed as the user types it, and does not have to press enter.

Comment: This is extremely vague. What exactly do you want the program to do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523174/raw-input-without-pressing-enter