# Is there a way prompt user for input and continue after set number of characters, so as to avoid waiting for the enter key in python 3?

Tags: python, user-input

I am trying to write a python typing test that displays 5 letter words from a list in a timed while loop of 60 seconds.  Everything works if the user presses enter after each typed word but this allows for backspacing and isn't my goal.  Is input() able to move on after 5 keys have been typed (including arrow keys and backspace key) without the enter key press? Just moving on to the next word as if enter was pressed?

```
import time
import random

                           
t_end = time.time() + 60    # Set timer for 60 seconds


correct = 0
incorrect = 0
wpm_count = 0
accuracy = 0

words=["buggy", "coder", "etc.."]    #TODO: put lots of 5-character words in a list

while time.time() < t_end:
    for word in random.sample(words, 1):
        print(word, end=" ")
        wpm_count += 1
        user_txt = input("  ")
        if (user_txt == word):
            correct += 1
            
        else:
            incorrect += 1

#Calculate and display results
accuracy = (correct / attempts ) * 100
print("=-=-=- Results: -=-=-= \nCorrect: " + str(correct) + " \nErrors: " + str(incorrect) + " \n Total WPM: " + str(attempts) + "\nAccuracy: " + str(accuracy) )
```

Comment: You could use getch (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523174/raw-input-without-pressing-enter)

Comment: Your example is not working, you forgot to set `wpm_count = 0`.

Comment: oops! fixed it, thank you!