# Comparing a KeyCode object to string in python

Tags: python, keycode, pynput

I'm trying to trigger functions on key presses in python. I'm using the pynput library's listen function, which returns a Keycode object.
I've tried casting the object to string but the following code still returns the following output (when pressing the 'a' key):

```
def on_press(key):
    mod = str(key)
    print(mod)
    print(type(mod))
    print(mod=='a')
```

I get:

```
'a'
< class 'str'>
False
```

Comment: Please take a look at this answer. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575650/how-to-obtain-the-keycodes-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575650/how-to-obtain-the-keycodes-in-python)

Comment: Good minimal, weird example. Are you using this as written? or comparing the string to the keycode object directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use next:

```
def on_press(key):
    print(key.char=='a')
```

Above will print `True`.

Your code cannot work just because:

```
mod = str(key)
print(mod)
```

Will get `'a'`, but for a normal string, `print('a')` will just print `a`, they are not the same string. You can confirm it with `print(len(mod))` & `print(len('a'))`

BTW, next is a full code for your test:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import sys

def on_press(key):
    mod = str(key)
    print(mod)
    print(type(mod))
    print(mod=='a')
    print(key.char=='a')
    print(len(mod))
    print(len('a'))
    sys.exit(0)

def on_release(key):
    pass

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```