# type as you go input for python, rerun code on change to input

Tags: python, elasticsearch, autocomplete

I'm trying to create an autocomplete demonstration using some data in elasticsearch. I have a simple code that takes an input, then returns a list of recommended autocompletes.

```
while True:
    search = input("start typing")

    body = {
         "size": 5,
         "query": {                                                     
             "multi_match": {
                 "query": "'"+search+"'"                         
             }                               
         }                
     }
    res = es.search(index="autocomplete", body=body) //getting the suggestions
    for hit in res['hits']['hits']:
        doc = hit["_source"]["company_name"]
        print(doc) //printing the suggestions
```

Right now it works like this:
Say I want to search for "Google". terminal will say `start typing!` and I'll type "G", press enter and I'll get a list of autocomplete suggestions, then it will say `start typing!` and I'll type "Go" and get a new list of suggestions, then next time I type "Goo", etc. just trying to see how the autocomplete suggestions change as I type more and more of the word.

I would like to get it to where if I type or change anything, it will automatically run the autocomplete code, so I can just type "G", it runs, then I type "o" which adds it to the previous "G" so it runs for "Go", then I type another "o", "g","l","e". Basically I want it to run like a normal autocomplete for Google search, where as you keep typing it will update the suggestions. Is there a way to do this in python?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to get it to where if I type or change anything, it will
> automatically run the autocomplete code

No, there is no out-of-the-box way to do this in Python; both the `input` and `raw_input` require the user to press `Enter`. Here are a few StackOverflow posts which discuss possible solutions:

- [How to read a single character from the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/how-to-read-a-single-character-from-the-user)
- [raw_input in python without pressing enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523174/raw-input-in-python-without-pressing-enter)
- [Polling the keyboard (detect a keypress) in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292095/polling-the-keyboard-detect-a-keypress-in-python)
- [How to obtain the keycodes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575650/how-to-obtain-the-keycodes-in-python)

The solution you choose will depend on whether you need cross platform support or not.